# SQL server XML query with xquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I'm trying to reach "row" data below using xquery on sql server.

```
DECLARE @xmlData XML
SET @xmlData = '
<Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <Header>
    <WorkContext xmlns="http://oracle.com/weblogic/soap/workarea/">rO0ABXdbABh3ZWJsb2duNDAAAA==</WorkContext>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <getReport xmlns:ns0="http://report_xml.org">
      <return>
        <pagekey>F1D96FB7ACFBA3BD5D5E77C5</pagekey>
        <rapor>
          <dataSet xmlns="http://report_xml.org/dataSet/201006">
            <dataTable>
              <id>ABC1</id>
              <row>
                <dim1>Paris</dim1>
                <dim2>Societe</dim2>
                <dim3>Car</dim3>
              </row>
              <row>
                <dim1>Paris</dim1>
                <dim2>Credit</dim2>
                <dim3>Car</dim3>
              </row>
            </dataTable>
          </dataSet>
        </rapor>
      </return>
    </getReport>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
'
```

When I use below code I can get the the "pagekey" value

```
; WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://report_xml.org/dataSet/201006' AS DS)
select @xmlData.query('/Envelope/Body/getReport/return/pagekey')
```

or I can reach the "dataSet" xml using this one

```
; WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://report_xml.org/dataSet/201006' AS DS)
select @xmlData.query('/Envelope/Body/getReport/return/rapor/DS:dataSet')
```

However, when I try to reach further down like

```
; WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://report_xml.org/dataSet/201006' AS DS)
select @xmlData.query('/Envelope/Body/getReport/return/rapor/DS:dataSet/dataTable/id')
or
select @xmlData.query('/Envelope/Body/getReport/return/rapor/DS:dataSet/dataTable/row')
```

Queries return empty.

what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dataSet` element introduces *default namespace* `http://report_xml.org/dataSet/201006`. Note that unlike *prefixed namespace*, descendant elements inherit *default namespace* from ancestor *implicitly*, so you should use the same prefix to access elements within `dataSet`:

```
; WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://report_xml.org/dataSet/201006' AS DS)
select @xmlData.query('/Envelope/Body/getReport/return/rapor/DS:dataSet/DS:dataTable/DS:id')
or
select @xmlData.query('/Envelope/Body/getReport/return/rapor/DS:dataSet/DS:dataTable/DS:row')
```